# Issue on Snort rules to track IRC servers activities

Tags: irc, snort, botnet

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"COMMUNITY BOT IRC Traffic Detected By Nick Change"; flow: to_server,established; content:"NICK "; nocase; offset: 0; depth: 5; flowbits:set,community_is_proto_irc; flowbits: noalert; classtype:misc-activity; sid:100000240; rev:3;)

alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"COMMUNITY BOT Internal IRC server detected"; flow: to_server,established; flowbits:isset,community_is_proto_irc; classtype: policy-violation; sid:100000241; rev:2;)

alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"CHAT IRC message from internal bot"; flow: established; flowbits:isset,community_is_proto_irc; content:"PRIVMSG "; nocase; classtype:policy-violation; sid:1463;)

The above rules have been written by [David Bianco](http://blog.vorant.com/2006/03/detecting-common-botnets-with-snort.html) to track IRC bot/server activity on any IRC port. However, the above rules works fine but I have a problem with them. My problem is happening when multiple IRC servers (some of them work on 7000 and the other work on 6667) run on the network some of them will  achieve the conditions of the rules and Snort will generate the alerts and some of them (or even one of them) will not achieve these condition and as a result Snort wont generate any alert related to the defined set. I think there's a kind of inconsistency. Any suggestions on that issue? I am working on Snort 2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God, the issue is resolved now.... The reason of the problem was a conflict between many rules which trying to trig at the same time for the same activity (PRIVMSG), so when I removed these rules, every think was just fine for the above rules.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what rules did you remove? The traffic doesn't hit multiple rules, it can only match one so I presume you removed the ones which were originally being hit?

Comment: In my case there were some rules try to capture PRIVMSG messages. So, I just commented the unwanted ones to get rid of its impact on the desired rules.

Answer (score 3):

These IRC rules are quite old and won't (as you've seen) capture all IRC traffic. It's almost impossible to say why they're not matching with a network capture or trace.

The first rule is set a flowbit based on the rule matching the traffic (based on an insenstitive match of the word 'NICK' from offset 0 for a depth of 5), if the first rule doesn't match the traffic then it won't set the flowbit to "community_is_proto_irc". Here's an old explanation on flowbits - http://forums.snort.org/forums/rules/topics/flowbits.

The second rule simply alerts on the presence of the flowbit (for traffic from external to home) whilst the third rule is more granular with a content match (and the traffic flow reversed).

I'd recommend getting a pcap for the non-matching IRC traffic and firing it through Snort locally to see what's being missed and then tailoring your rules accordingly (snort -r test.pcap -c /etc/snort_test.conf) - http://manual.snort.org/node8.html.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, but my problem is with tagging multiple online IRC servers running simultaneously.

Comment: So does this traffic not contain the string "NICK " in the first 5 bytes?

Comment: Have you taken a capture and re-run it through Snort with your config file?

Comment: Yes, some of the servers captured and some not.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the minute is that they're not part of the $HOME_NET variable in the snort.conf file....nothing-else coming to my mind at the minute.

Comment: All the servers are in $HOME_NET. For example, when you do a test on Vmware both 192.168.1.2 that has Dst. port 7000 and 192.168.1.3 that has Dst. port 6667 may be captured, but when you repeat the same test, only one my be captured by these rules. I hope you get my point. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Where are you looking for the capture? In something like Sguil, Snorby etc? Or the Snort log alerts file/directory?